# "Failed to decompress a compressed WebSocket frame" error in Tomcat WebSocket

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, websocket, jsr356

I have a JavaScript WebSocket client and Tomcat WebSocket server (**JSR 356**). Whenever I try sending text data to the server from the JS client, I'm receiving the following error

> Failed to decompress a compressed WebSocket frame

The WebSocket session was closed with the CloseCode `1002`. This issue occurs only in specific machine (JS ClientEndpoint). Moreover when this error is encountered, the text messages that I sent from ClientEndpoint were received incorrectly by ServerEndpoint

I tried searching for a solution to this issue in the internet. But nothing is relevant. Does anyone have a solution for this ?

Comment: Can you provide some code or Tomcat configuratiin ?

Comment: @Marged Thanks for your response. I'm sorry I can't provide the code. But I can tell you about Tomcat configuration. May I know what are all the details you need to know about Tomcat ?

Comment: Without code this will be complicated. When it comes to Tomcat the ws configuration and the version would be helpful.

Comment: @Marged I'm using Tomcat 8. The issue occurred when the data was transferred through a non-secure WebSocket session. The max text message buffer size was set as 2000000 bytes. I'll try to provide the minimized working sample of this code meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out that **FortiClient's antivirus** application that is running in the client machine is the reason behind this issue. Once we disabled this antivirus application, the issue seems to be resolved.

I still don't know how it happened. It needs to be analyzed. Meanwhile any relevant information regarding this issue appreciated.